# Лучшее решение для работы с большим количеством объектов

Tags: android

Нужно парсить овермного данных. Для этого будет создано примерно 3-4 таблицы в которые будет добавлено 5000-80к объектов. Нужно их сохранять и потом делать выборки различные и чтобы это работало быстро, в пределах 10-15 сек от запроса до вывода результатов. Начал с Realm-a но, понял что с выборками там сложно ибо мне нужно например `Where table1.name = table2.name`, в Realm надо использовать циклы что при 60к объектов долго.

Подскажите куда смотреть?

Comment: А все эти объекты относятся к одному классу или к разным???

Answer (score 1):

На меньше чем 100 тысячах объектов даже без индексов обычный MySQL будет справляться с задачей в обозначенное время. Если же сделать индексы, то и того быстрее.

Например, поиск по текстовому полю без индекса в БД из 500000 разнородных записей объёмом примерно в полтора гигабайта возвращает результаты через примерно 5 секунд. На ваших объёмах будет и того быстрее.

Можно говорить что у вас "овермного данных" если они не помещаются в оперативную память сервера, который в принципе можно купить или арендовать. Всё, что можно поместить в ОЗУ одного обычного сервера, не big data.

Comment: Судя по метке, речь в вопросе идёт про мобильное устройство на ОС Андроид, то есть ни MySQL ни сервера здесь неприменимы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Для быстрой выборки объектов придется писать параллельный алгоритм. Например, 10 потоков обрабатывают по 500 записей, потом складывают результаты и передают то, что нужно вызывающему классу. Условие: все данные должны быть в ОЗУ или БД должна успевать за скоростью обработки.

   Если список сортированный и может делать выборку, которую поддерживают алгоритмы быстрой выборки — используйте сложные, но очень эффективные алгоритмы (см. гугл).
2. Как быстро отобразить 60 000 элементов — не знаю. Все зависит от средства отображения. Но я бы, на Вашем месте, по этому поводу не заморачивался, а подгружал бы все постепенно. Человек и 100 элементов за секунду не обработает. Хотя все зависит от сложности данных, 60 000 строк, думаю, можно отобразить за пару секунд.